# Links doesn't work on simple drop menu

Tags: html, css, submenu

I am stuck with a drop down menu that example I found at the following url : http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

The problem is with the hyper links, I tried to put `<li><a href="#">about</></li>` within the dropdown but it does not work like the cell over link.

Thanks for the help

```
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 20px 50px 150px;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
background: #555;
color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
background: #555; 
display: block; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
} 



<ul><li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>
Portfolio
<ul>
  <li>Web Design</li>
  <li>Web Development</li>
  <li>Illustrations</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try reformat your question using the 'code' formatter, because it's not clear atm

Comment: You also need to style the `a`-tag.. Browsers uses a default stylesheet that makes them purple

Comment: what do you mean by "like the cell over link"? What are the menu entries supposed to do when clicked?

Comment: Can you rephrase "but it does not work like the cell over link."? This is entirely unclear. Also, I edited your question back to how (I think) the 2nd paragraph was. Did you intend (or in fact, actually) write `<li><a href="#">about</a></li>` instead of `<li><a href="#">about</></li>`?

Comment: Yes! thanks! now the link looks fine. How can i do now for making click with the mouse not only in the text and also in the hover cell for making the link work. Now its only working when you click over the text but not when you click in the rest of the hover cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul><li>Home</li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>Portfolio<ul>
        <li>Web Design</li>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

try something like this i changed `<li><a href="#">About</a></li>` You forgot to close `</a>`

**EDIT:**

add this to your css file. If this is what you mean

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Also, check out this example with the answered code used. Is this what you are looking for?
http://cssdeck.com/labs/qcjphxx1

Comment: Thanks,

Yes i forgot to close, the links appears but only ass text hyperlink. I mean the cell hover change color and active link fine but to click the link only over the text thats met big problem

Comment: I found in that that site the code, and in the example works great (without the hyperlinks). when i put the links become the problem

Comment: I dont understand you? what is it that you want with that link? you want to have it just as the rest of the buttons?

Comment: here:  http://www.expedicionsonrisa.com/proyecto2.html    in the first link "el proyecto", the only one with the link, its where the problem is

Comment: Yes! thanks! now the link looks fine. How can i do now for making click with the mouse not only in the text and also in the hover cell for making the link work. Now its only working when you click over the text but not when you click in the rest of the hover cell. Sorry my english